# Original article about a theorem of Cartan on iterations of analytic functions

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, cv.complex-variables

I'd like to know in which paper of H. Cartan I could find the following theorem :

Let $\Omega$ be a connected, open and bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $a \in \Omega$ and $f \in H(\Omega,\Omega)$ with $f(a) = a$ and set $f_n = f o \ldots o f$ (n times).
Then
1) $\mid f'(a)\mid \le 1$
2) $\mid f'(a)\mid = 1 \Leftrightarrow f \in Aut (\Omega)$
3) $\mid f'(a)\mid \lt 1 \Rightarrow f_n \rightarrow^{uc} \phi_a $, where $\phi_a \in H(\Omega)$ is the constant function defined by $\phi_a(z) = a$ for every z in $\Omega$

Comment: This statement is known as the Schwarz lemma in the case of the disc, and Pick's Theorem or the Schwarz-Pick Lemma when transferred to the hyperbolic metric of general domains. (Here there isn't the assumption that a is fixed, and the conclusion in 2) being that f is a covering map. Your statement follows from this version.) Unfortunately I can't say that I really know the history of the statement. On what basis do you think it should have been first stated in this form by Cartan?

Comment: Do you mean that $f(\Omega)\subseteq \Omega$ implies that $|f'(a)|\leq 1$ ?

Comment: Thanks for these answers and sorry for the delay.
@LasseRempe-Gillen : I saw it it a textbook of H. Quéffellec & C. Zuily entitled "Eléments d'Analyse" (p. 153 of the 2nd edition). 
Since I wanted to use similar arguments in my next paper, I wanted to know if there was not a more general statement. Indeed, it could generalize it, but it would be unnecessary if it's already done.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. : in the proof, this inequality is indeed a consequence of the f-stability of $\Omega$ by applying Cauchy inequalities and also using the fact that a is a fixed point.

Comment: If you are looking for a generalization in complex dimension 1, then this is given by the (hyperbolic version of) the Schwarz lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Cartan's theorem (1931) is the extension of Schwarz's lemma to multivariable functions. See [The Schwarz lemma at the boundary](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1805), page 9.

H. Cartan, *Les fonctions de deux variables complexes et le problème de la représentation analytique*, J. Math. Pures Appl. **19** (1931) 1-114.

Comment: Thanks for this precise answer :-)
That's what I was seeking.

Comment: I've quickly read the article, but it seems that the theorem I stated is not mentioned. Of course, there are some similarities with the Schwartz lemma, but it is quite different.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Carlo, the result of Cartan that you may be looking for is actually a generalization of the Schwarz lemma to several variables. I think the paper in question may be

H. Cartan, *Sur les fonctions de deux variables complexes. Les transformations d’un domaine borné $D$ en un domaine intérieur à $D$*, Bulletin de la Société Mathématique de France (1930)
Volume: 58, page 199-219. https://eudml.org/doc/86572

Assuming that you are interested in the one-dimensional version as stated above, it follows from the original Schwarz lemma together with the uniformization theorem (proved by Poincaré and Koebe). I would suggest looking at the sources cited in [the Encyclopedia of Mathematics entry](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Schwarz_lemma), which refers in particular to "The Schwarz lemma" by Dineen and pp. 191-192 of "An introduction to classical complex analysis" by Burchel. (I do not have these books to hand.)

Comment: OK, thanks for these useful additional details :-)

Comment: I've quickly read the article, but it seems that the theorem I stated is not mentioned. Of course, there are some similarities with the Schwartz lemma, but it is quite different.

Comment: As stated in my answer, if you are looking for the theorem that you state, this is the Schwarz lemma, via covering theory.